# php strtotime "2 Sunday ago"

Tags: php, strtotime

At the date/time of this error, it is, "3/24/2014 7:08AM". Normally, running "2 Sunday ago" on strtotime() will result in going back to 2 sundays. So it'll result in, 3/16. However, it is landing on 3/23, which is last sunday. Also, running "1 Sunday ago" will result in a future date of 3/30 and not 3/23. I'm assuming its some kind of settings issue but don't know how to debug. Any help would be great.

Thanks!

```
$start = date( "Y-m-d 11:00:00", strtotime("2 Sunday ago"));
$end = date( "Y-m-d 11:00:00", strtotime("Last Sunday"));
echo $start . ' - ' . $end;
```

Comment: [Cannot Reproduce](http://codepad.viper-7.com/3NWyJB).

Comment: Never mind what date _you_ think it is, ask the computer: `$today = date( "Y-m-d 11:00:00", strtotime("now")); echo $today;`. It may have a different idea.

Comment: Not sure why i got the down vote as it clearly is a problem and a solution was posted. If someone is not able to reproduce this we should figure out why I'm seeing it, and not down vote.

Comment: I had the same problem. The solution here was perfect. Whoever down-voted this is a jerk.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try with

```
 $start = date( "Y-m-d 11:00:00", strtotime("-2 weeks sunday"));
 $end = date( "Y-m-d 11:00:00", strtotime("-1 weeks sunday"));
 echo $start . ' - ' . $end;
```

Comment: Same issue, i'm getting 2014-03-23 - 2014-03-23 using that.

Comment: nevermind that, this does work. I had an exit on my code and was only looking at my output.

Comment: Kindly mark it answered if it works for you

Comment: have any ideas to why "2 sunday ago" doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks to this, I now have an idea how to select records more than 3 months ago `new MongoDate(strtotime("-3 months"))`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$start = date( "Y-m-d 11:00:00", strtotime("-2 sunday"));
$end = date( "Y-m-d 11:00:00", strtotime("last sunday"));
echo $start . ' - ' . $end;
?>
```

[example](http://codepad.org/QlYgqeKJ)

Answer (score 0):

Your Code is Working Fine with PHP version 5.3+ check it [here](http://3v4l.org/OpT78)

You can use `-2 weeks sunday` instead it works on all (4.3+) PHP versions check out [here](http://3v4l.org/6PqT6)

Comment: Just fyi, I am on php version 5.1. Not 5.3 but definitely 4.3+